# Is it a bug in MSVC 2010 or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

Consider following code snippet:

In database_sqlite.h:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) SQLiteDatabase : public Database
{
    virtual void GetTableProperties(DatabaseTable *table, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg);
protected:
    struct SQLiteImpl;
};

struct SQLiteDatabase::SQLiteImpl
{
    std::wstring m_catalog;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > m_myconv;
};
```

In database_sqlite.cpp:

```
void SQLiteDatabase::GetTableProperties(DatabaseTable *table, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    std::wstring errorMessage;
    int result;
    std::wstring query = L"SELECT * FROM \"sys.abcattbl\" WHERE \"abt_tnam\" = ? AND \"abt_ownr\" = ?;";
    const unsigned char *dataFontName, *headingFontName, *labelFontName;
    int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2( m_db, sqlite_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query.c_str() ).c_str(), (int) query.length(), &stmt, 0 );
    if( res == SQLITE_OK )
    {
const char *name = sqlite_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( table->GetTableName().c_str() ).c_str(); // I used this line for debugging purposes
    res = sqlite3_bind_text( stmt, 1, sqlite_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( table->GetTableName().c_str() ).c_str(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC );
    if( res == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        res = sqlite3_bind_text( stmt, 2, sqlite_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( table->GetSchemaName().c_str() ).c_str(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC );
        if( res == SQLITE_OK )
        {
            while( true )
            {
```

char *result_query = sqlite3_expanded_sql( stmt );
                    res = sqlite3_step( stmt );

Here *result_query contains = "SELECT * FROM "sys.abcattbl" WHERE "abt_tnam" = '' AND "abt_ownr" = '';"
I'm using MSVC2010 and, to my surprise, "*name" contains empty string. The first call to "to_bytes()" succeeded, since I can check the query that will be used.

Do I have to do something after the first call to "to_bytes()"? Or I simply have to upgrade the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you're doing something wrong.

I don't actually now what `to_bytes` returns, but I'll assume that it is a type base on `std::basic_string`, so `std::string` and family.

`to_bytes` returns a temporary object to that string instance, so when you call `c_str()`, your getting a pointer to the first character of a string that will no longer exist after the statements finishes. You basically have undefined behavior, due to `name` being a dangling pointer and you trying to output it.

You'll have to allocate memory and copy the string to it, or just use `std::string`, where does types of problems do not occur.

The reason why your call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds is because the string returned by `to_bytes` still exists. The string is destroyed when the statement ends, so when `res` is assigned the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. Not before, and thus the call succeeds, as a valid pointer to a string is passed.

And nonetheless, please upgrade your compiler.

Comment: but then how come the call to "sqlite3_prepare_v2()" succeeded? Also, please check my edit - I am adding more code. Thx.

Comment: everything works now. Changing the "sqlite3_bind_text()" last parameter to "SQLITE_TRANSIENT" fixed the issue. For some reason I was pretty sure I needed SQLITE_STATIC. Thx again and Happy New Year.